# What should I read before Batman, Incorporated?

Tags: comics, dc, batman, suggested-order, batman-inc

I have read the first two comics in the new Batman, Incorporated and find myself scratching my head a lot at apparently existing characters (Goatboy? Leviathan? Dead Heroes Club?  And that's just #1) that aren't explained.  There's even a beholder on the cover of #2!  WTF!

Are there some previous Batman or Batman, Incorporated arcs that I should be reading before the new series in order to make more sense of this all?

Comment: Batman Incorporated is just a collection of random cells all bound together in a single issue. As far as I can tell nothing on any single page has anything to do with any other page.

Comment: So, not just me then.  Good! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In September of 2011, DC relaunched all their books. This event was called the New 52. Prior to that, there was another *Batman Incorporated* book that went from November 2010 to December 2011. This series is collected in a trade paperback (available on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401232124)).

In May of 2012, they started the series back up with issue #1 but picked up were they left off prior to the New 52. I would give that trade paperback a read prior to reading the new series. It will make much more sense (albeit not complete sense).

If you are still confused after reading that, try reading the other Grant Morrison Batman books. Wikipedia has a great article on [Batman Incorporated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Incorporated).

Answer (score 2):

The Grant Morrison Batman Saga (of which the current Batman Inc. title is supposedly the final act) can be read in these collected editions:

- **Batman and Son** containing Batman v1 655-658, 663-666
- **Batman: The Resurrection of Ra's al Ghul** containing Batman v1 670-671, Annual 26; Robin v2 168-169, Annual 7; Nightwing v1 138-139; Detective Comics v1 838-839
- **Batman: The Black Glove** containing Batman v1 667-669, 672-675
- **Batman RIP** containing Batman v1 676-683
- **Final Crisis** containing Final Crisis 1-7, and others
- Batman: Battle for the Cowl (optional, not by Morrison)
- **Batman and Robin: Batman Reborn** containing Batman and Robin 1-6
- **Batman and Robin: Batman vs Robin** containing Batman and Robin 7-12
- **Batman: Time and the Batman** containing Batman v1 700-703
- **Batman: The Return of Bruce Wayne** containing Batman: The Return of
  Bruce Wayne 1-6
- **Batman and Robin: Batman and Robin Must Die!** containing Batman and
  Robin 13-16, Batman: The Return
- **Batman Incorporated Volume One** containing Batman Incorporated 1-8,
  Batman Incorporated: Leviathan Strikes

There are, of course, a number of other titles that explore the evolving Batman status quo throughout these stories, but I believe that list to be the spine of the tale.